# How to change one object's color while useing Flatlaf

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton, flatlaf

1. This will change all the JRadioButton's checkmark color.

   ```
   UIManager.put( "CheckBox.icon.checkmarkColor", Color.red );
   LookAndFeel lookAndFeel = UIManager.getLookAndFeel();
   try {
       UIManager.setLookAndFeel( lookAndFeel );
   } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   updateUI();
   ```
2. And then I want to only change **radiobutton1**'s  color while I click another button.
   But it does not work.

   ```
   radiobutton1.putClientProperty( "CheckBox.icon.checkmarkColor",Color.yellow);
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use "style" can do this.

```
radiobutton1.putClientProperty( FlatClientProperties.STYLE,"icon.checkmarkColor:#ffff66");
```

This can change only radiobutton1's "icon.checkmarkColor".